# Dhall Association List

Tags: dhall

I have a Union type that I wish one field to be an association list.

```
let Blah = < First : { name : Text, params: XXX } | Second : { name : Text } >
```

Here, I wish `params` to be an association list so when I type check Record values it will pass, e.g.

```
Blah.First { name = "Alex", params: [{ mapKey = "a", mapValue = 1 }] }
```

So, what type should `XXX` be in `Blah`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the type of value stored in the association list.  In the most general case, you can parametrize the `Blah` type on the type of the `mapValue`, like this:

```hs
let Blah =
        λ(a : Type)
      → < First :
            { name : Text, params : List { mapKey : Text, mapValue : a } }
        | Second :
            { name : Text }
        >

in  (Blah Natural).First
    { name = "Alex", params = [ { mapKey = "a", mapValue = 1 } ] }
```

If you know the desired `mapValue` type ahead of time, you can hard-code it instead of making `Blah` a function of a type.  Or, if you plan to use `Blah` for the same `mapValue` type multiple times, you can do something like this:

```hs
let Blah =
        λ(a : Type)
      → < First :
            { name : Text, params : List { mapKey : Text, mapValue : a } }
        | Second :
            { name : Text }
        >

let Foo = Blah Natural

in  [ Foo.First { name = "Alex", params = [ { mapKey = "a", mapValue = 1 } ] }
    , Foo.Second { name = "John" }
    ]
```